# A closed set A in some topological space (X,τ) such that $A^c$ is not in τ.

Tags: general-topology

We say a set $A$ in a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is closed if $A^c$ is in $\tau$. So it is possible for some $A$ that if $A^c$ is not in $\tau$ then still $A$ is closed.

(But I could not find such a closed set $A$ in some $(X,\tau)$ such that $A^c$ is not in $\tau$. Please give some hints or examples.)

Comment: "So it is possible for some $A$ that if $A^c$ is not in $\tau$ then still $A$ is closed" -- No, that's not possible. The definition of being closed the complement being open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequent wording of definitions is the following:

> We say that $X$ has property $Y$ *if* it is $Z$ and has $W$.

But when used in definitions (as opposed to statements), that *if* is meant to stand for **equivalence**, i.e. $X$ has property $Y$ *if and only if* it is $Z$ and has $W$.

So in fact a set $A$ is closed *if and only if* $A^c$ is in $\tau$, hence it is not possible for $A^c$ to not be in $\tau$ while $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a closed set is the complementary of an open set, so such $A$ doesn't exist.